# How to set background color for images in Fotorama plugin?

Tags: fotorama

Fotorama jQuery [plugin](http://fotorama.io/)

In this plugin i use transparent PNG images. I need to set background color for images.
I tried to set style, but it didn't work.

```
 <div class="fotorama">
 <img style="background-color: #ffff00" src="/slider/image1.png">
 <img style="background-color: #ffff00" src="/slider/image1.png">
 </div>
```

Comment: Try to set style on container div, if just one color is in question... or better inspect created elements and find one which holds images... fotorama create html

Comment: I set style to div. in this way all slider has background color with thumbnails. I saw page source code in browser but i don't see raw html fotorama. it still one div block with class fotorama

Comment: you should use some developer tools - html created with javascript is not visible in page source, because it is added later...will check it now...

Comment: Thanks! i found this class .fotorama__img{
    background-color: saddlebrown;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.fotorama__wrap--slide .fotorama__stage__frame {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    background-color: #FF0;
}
```

Find this classes in CSS, and add your bg-color rule... Btw, you can use developer tools in firefox, chrome, ie... (F12 will open it) and inspect element(s). That way, you can check/debug html/css/js easily... Note: this is solution for latest version of fotorama, not sure that class names are same in previous versions...